# Trying to post data to same page

Tags: jquery, html, django, python-2.7

I'm learning Python (& Django) while building a site. I've managed to learn quite a bit but am having problems understanding the tools available and what I should be using.

The problem I'm trying to solve:
I have a list of links. When a link is clicked, I need to query some data and then display that data on the same page without refreshing or reloading the page.

```
#urls.py
url(r'^post/query:(?P<minion_id>[^/]+)/$', views.get_miniondetail, name='get_miniondetail')

#views.py --note ignore file system it is a test output
def get_miniondetail(request, minion_id):
    print 'in get_miniondetail: ' + minion_id + '\r'

    detail = minion_id
    context = {'minion_detail': detail}

    html_string = '<html>' + detail + '</html>'

    f = open('test.html', 'w+')
    f.write(html_string)
    f.close()

    return HttpResponse(html_string, mimetype='text/plain')

<!-- html  -->
<a href="post/query:{{ minion.name }}">{{ minion.name }}</a>
```

Should I be calling a javascript function instead of a link with the url mapped to `get_miniondetail`? I've not been able to wrap my head around the forms yet. So I am wondering if jQuery will get done what I need ...and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things either missing in your code or not done the django way. But since you are trying to get it work, I would suggest you the following:

Note: code has not been tested. But few things to correct in your code:

1. Avoid using colons in URL. a forward slash would be cleaner.
2. The context you are setting here is almost useless as you are not using it anywhere to render a template.
3. If you want to load something without refreshing the page. You must you Ajax call. jquery functions may come handy.

   `#url.py
   url(r'^post/query/(?P<minion_id>[^/]+)/$', views.get_miniondetail, name='get_miniondetail')`

   ```
   #views.py --note ignore file system it is a test output    
   def get_miniondetail(request, minion_id):

       detail = minion_id
       context = {'minion_detail': detail}

       html_string = '<html>' + detail + '</html>'

       f = open('test.html', 'w+')
       f.write(html_string)
       f.close()

       return HttpResponse(html_string, mimetype='text/plain')
   ```

   ## html

   ```
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link1">{{ minion.name }}</a>
   <div id="result1"></div>
   <script>

     $('#link1').click($('#result1').load('post/query/{{ minion.name }}'));
   </script>
   ```

Comment: I have multiple items in the list so I'm using a class. I now have a jQuery function that gives me an alert with the minion name. Next is the load portion. Thanks!

Comment: Is 'result1' correct in the `click($('result1`).load(...)`? Should that be `#result1`? and are there some missing close parens `)`?

Comment: @IAbstract Thanks for pointing out. However, as I said the code is not tested.

Answer (score 1):

To display data without refreshing or reloading the page, you'd definitely need some sort of a javascript framework like jQuery or backbone. You'd use django to fetch JSON feeds, and then use jQuery on the browser side to refresh the data part of the page.

Some links to check out are
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
http://backbonejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some very very odd things here. The oddest of all is that you are for some reason writing your HTML output to the filesystem: not only is there absolutely no reason to do this, but you will immediately run into problems in a real system because many different processes will be trying to write to the same place.

But there are other strange things too: hard-coding the HTML string instead of using a template; the odd URL format; outputting the template code instead of rendering it...

You should really do the tutorial. *All* of the things you are having problems with are dealt with there.

Comment: The file system was simply a test.